# Проблема с JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, сокет

Пытаюсь передавать с одного компа на другой сообщения через сокеты. Всё отлично работает. Потом пытаюсь на компе-приёмнике выводить полученные значения непрерывно через JavaFX. Компьютер-сервер опознаёт, что к нему подсоединился компьютер-клиент, но программа на клиенте зависает без всяких сообщений об ошибке. При этом если убрать цикл while в программе клиента, то программа не зависает (принимает одно значение, выводит, и закрывает потоки). Нужно, что бы значений обновлялись непрерывно. В чём может быть косяк? Заранее благодарю за ответы

**Controller.java**

```
 package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField textfield;

    @FXML
    private void ButtonPushed (ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 3345);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

               while (!socket.isOutputShutdown()) 
                textfield.setText(in.readUTF());
                in.close();
                socket.close(); 
    }
}
```

**sample.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" prefHeight="788.0" prefWidth="1217.0" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="874.0" prefWidth="1293.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="textfield" layoutX="73.0" layoutY="271.0" />
            <Button layoutX="126.0" layoutY="121.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ButtonPushed" text="Button1" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

**UPD**

**MyRunnable**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyRunnable  implements Runnable {

    private int var;

    public MyRunnable() {
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 3345);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            while (!socket.isOutputShutdown()) {
                Controller controller = new Controller();
                String s=in.readUTF();
                System.out.println(s);
                Platform.runLater(() -> controller.setTextfield(s)); //NullPointerException
            }
            System.out.print("out");
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("CrocoBot");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
        t.start();
        System.out.print("sfesf");
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вынести логику работы с сокетами в отдельный поток. Вы же это делаете в FX потоке, предназначенном только для обновления UI. Вот программа и ждет пока завершится бесконечный цикл, что бы отобразить результат.

После получения данных от сокет потока, отправить данные на обновления UI можно
через конструкцию Platform.runLater

Comment: Добрый вечер, спасибо, что откликнулись. Вынес логику в отдельный класс. Теперь возникает NullPointerException ( код класса указал в тексте проблемы). Не подскажите, что я сделал неправильно?

Comment: Вы создали новый экземпляр контроллера и все поля в нем соответственно не инициализированы. Нужный экземпляр можно получить либо из Main, если вынести FXMLLoader отдельной переменной, после метода load() из него можно забрать контроллер, либо непосредственно из контроллера из метода инициализации например в статическую переменную упрятать MyRunnable.setController(this).


Так же обратите внимание, что ваш блок когда с сокетами стартует раньше чем контроллер, так что его надо будет проверять на null. fxml.load() достаточная долгая операция

Comment: Знаю, что здесь не приняты столь неконструктивные сообщения, но всё же большое вам спасибо. В Java совершенно на разбираюсь, а потребность возникла) без вас бы очень долго, наверное, разбирался